# Polar coordinates when $(x,y)$ approach to infinity

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function such that infinity is an accumulation point. Can I use the polar coordinates to calculate the limit of $f$ when $(x,y)$ approach to infinity? If the answer is not, there exists a Counter-example?

Comment: Yes of course, you can!

Comment: The question is not how $f$ looks like. When you have a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ of Cartesian coordinates that describe points tending to infinity and express this in polar coordinates it does not change the fact that the points of the sequence tend to infinity. It probably helps if you attempt to express this in concrete formulas.